# How to Setup Kafka Streams Message Compression?

Tags: apache-kafka, compression, bigdata, apache-kafka-streams

Using Kafka Streams, we were unable to identify the configuration required to compress messages written to the sink topic after they've been processed.

On the other hand, using the classic Kafka Producer, compression is easily achieved by setting the configuration "compression.type" on the [KafkaProducer properties](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs)

However, there doesn't seem to be any documented example of having Kafka Streams compress the processed messages.

As for this time (beginning of 2019), is there a way to use compression with Kafka Streams at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify parameters for the internally used producer in StreamConfig, as shown below:

```
final Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "your-streams-app-id");
props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "lz4");
```

The output topics will be compressed using LZ4 algorithm.

See https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#kafka-consumers-producer-and-admin-client-configuration-parameters for further details.